# Отминусовать в mysql от поля decimal 16,8 дробь

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть mysql decimal16,8 - запись вида 123.12345678

Если отминусовывать в sql запросе

```
decimal = decimal - '1.23456789'
```

Неизбежны неточности. Если использовать 2 запроса - один на получение данных, другой на update , а посередине bcsub - получается слишком много кода.

Как в одном запросе отминусовать с точностью bcsub ?

Comment: Вы реально увидели "неточность"? Или так, на всякий случай...

Comment: Я в самом php видел

Comment: А если явно - `SET decimal = decimal - CAST('1.23456789' AS DECIMAL)`  ?